# How to make sure input is not empty?

Tags: javascript, css, html, numbers, phonegap

I'm building a PhoneGap app for practice which means I wish to avoid jQuery at all costs, no arguments accepted. I have an input type with working buttons but if the user deletes all the numbers leaving a blank input field and then presses a plus or minus button, it reports in the input box "Nan". How to make it instead set to "0"?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var CapsNum = localStorage.getItem("CapsNum");

  if (CapsNum == null) {
    setCapsNum = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("caps").value = CapsNum;
  }
}
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  localStorage.setItem("CapsNum", document.getElementById("caps").value);
}

function PlusCaps() {
 var nextValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("caps").value) + 1;
  console.log(nextValue);
  setNextValue(nextValue);
}

function MinusCaps() { 
var nextValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("caps").value) - 1; 

// If the next value is valid... 
if (nextValue >=0) { 

// Set the next value. 
setNextValue(nextValue); 
} 
}

function setNextValue(nextValue) {
  localStorage.setItem("CapsNum", nextValue);
  document.getElementById("caps").value = nextValue;
}

function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
```

```css
.button {
 font-size: 18px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 line-height: 20px;
 vertical-align: top;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 1);
 -moz-border-radius: 8px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

#caps {
 margin-top:12px;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 font-size: 35px;
 width: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 background: TRANSPARENT;
 color: YELLOW;
 border: 2px solid;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="CapsButton" tabindex="1">
<input type="button" id="minus" class="button" value="-" style="margin-right:10px" onclick="MinusCaps()" />
<input type="tel" id="caps" maxlength="3" size="3" pattern="[0-9]+" value="" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
<input type="button" id="plus" class="button" value="+" style="margin-left:10px" onclick="PlusCaps()" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isNaN(). This function returns true if the value equates to NaN. Otherwise it returns false. For example:

```
if(isNaN(document.getElementById("caps").value)){
   document.getElementById("caps").value = 0;
}
```

EDITED
The problem is that document.getElementById("caps").value returns empty string
and parceInt("") = NaN
So you can use:

```
function ifInputEmpty(){
  if(document.getElementById("caps").value === ""){
     return 0;
  } else {
     return parseInt(document.getElementById("caps").value);
  }
}
```

Fore PlusCaps

```
function PlusCaps() {
  var prevVal = ifInputEmpty();
  var nextValue = prevVal + 1;
  console.log(nextValue);
  setNextValue(nextValue);
}
```

Comment: I was researching isNaN but wasn't sure where or how to instert it. Where do I put it?

Comment: How do I get MinusCaps to set the input to 0 if it's blank and they click the minus button? PlusCaps works beautifully, thanks. :)

Comment: Same as for PlusCaps var prevVal = ifInputEmpty();

Comment: But how to get it to put a 0 in the input box instead of doing nothing, is what I mean? If it's blank and they press -, I want a zero put. If it's blank and they hit enter, I want a zero put. How to achieve that?